# can python multiproccess async functions?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, multiprocessing

im trying to multiproccess 2 functions at once. one of these functions is a websocket connection continuosly sending messages to a django site. the other is just an endless loop. i get no output from my second function.

here is my script

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

async def SendSMS():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000/ws/endpoint/chat/', ping_interval=None) as websocket:
        # await websocket.send(json.dumps({'message': f'red', 'token': 'hello'}))
        i = 0
        while True:
            i+=1
            if i%2==0:
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({'message': f'red', 'token': 'hello'}))
                print(str(i)+"   were saying red")
            else:
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({'message': f'green', 'token': 'hello'}))
                print(str(i)+"   were saying green")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

import time
def function2():#
    while True:
        print("popopopopopopopopop")
        time.sleep(1)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    p1 = Process(target=loop.run_until_complete(SendSMS()))
    p2 = Process(target=function2)
    p2.start()
    p1.start()
    p2.join()
    p1.join()
```

its almost like function2 never starts

here is some output

```
 C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\New folder (57)\mi_external_websocket\external.py:47: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
1   were saying green
2   were saying red
3   were saying green
4   were saying red
5   were saying green
6   were saying red
```

can python multiproccess async functions?

why do i get no output from my second function?

####### update

apparantly the problem is passing my function to the proccess like i am doing, calls it imediatley and we never get passed that line.

i originally called my async function (before multiprocessing) like this

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(SendSMS())
```

how can set up a multiprocessed process, which is async?

ive tried the following options

attempt 1)

```
p1 = Process(target=lambda: loop.run_until_complete(SendSMS()))
```

i get errors saying

```
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x0000019AEEEF01F0>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

and

```
 line 102, in spawn_main
    source_process = _winapi.OpenProcess(
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrec
```

attempt 2)

```
p1 = Process(target = SendSMS)
```

i get...

```
    popopopopopopopopop
C:\Users\tgmjack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py:108: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SendSMS' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
popopopopopopopopop
popopopopopopopopop
popopopopopopopopop
```

attempt 3)

```
p1 = Process(target = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(SendSMS))
```

i get ...

```
C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\New folder (57)\mi_external_websocket\external.py:44: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  p1 = Process(target = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(SendSMS))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\New folder (57)\mi_external_websocket\external.py", line 44, in <module>
    p1 = Process(target = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(SendSMS))
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 625, in run_until_complete
    future = tasks.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 615, in ensure_future
    return _ensure_future(coro_or_future, loop=loop)
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 630, in _ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

Comment: When does `SendSMS()` complete?

Comment: never it just continuosly sends message after message , the django page recieves the messages and changes the colour of a div to red or green accordingly

Comment: Because your code never get's passed this line: `p1 = Process(target=loop.run_until_complete(SendSMS()))`, it actually never gets passed this: `loop.run_until_complete(SendSMS())`, the `Process` expects a *callable*.

Comment: So, try for example, `def foo(): while True: print("hi"); time.sleep(2)` then do `p1 = Process(target=foo())`

Comment: ok, so its getting stuck when im setting up the Proccess. 

but how can i set up a process with asyn... ive updated my question with a bunch of attempts and results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't be passing an eventloop or an async function to `multiprocessing.Process` as they are not "simple datatypes" (serializable), they are associated with OS specific handles, and cannot be trivially passed between processes.

instead you need the child process to execute a function that will create the eventloop in the child process and have it execute your intended function, using `asyncio.run`, this function should be defined in the global scope, so that it is accessible by the child process.

```py
import asyncio

from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import freeze_support


async def SendSMS():
    while True:
        print("SendSMS")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


def send_SMS_caller():
    asyncio.run(SendSMS())


import time


def function2():  #
    while True:
        print("function2", flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    p1 = Process(target=send_SMS_caller)
    p2 = Process(target=function2)
    p2.start()
    p1.start()
    p2.join()
    p1.join()
```